# ¿Es posible en Python3 crear palabras reservadas?

Tags: python-3.x, sintaxis

Sucede que de momento pues pensé eso. No sé a qué exactamente le daría utilidad, pues apenas lo pensé, busque en Google y no conseguí documentación o referencias. Talvez es porque me decidí ir a por stackoverflow. Sí hay alguna forma de crear palabras reservadas porfavor me dejan saber. Sería un experimento bastante curioso.

Comment: Si. Baja los fuentes de Python y modificalos para crear tus propias palabras reservadas. El resultado, lamentablemente, no será Python.

Comment: ¿que entiendes por palabra reservada? ¿podrías dar un ejemplo?

Comment: Hay un [PEP que añade soporte de macros sintácticos](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0638/#id25), creo que es lo más parecido a agregar "palabras reservadas" sin recompilar Python.

Comment: Hola @Patricio Moracho, a palabras reservadas me refiero a estos por ejemplo: break, continue, return...

Comment: Ok, entonces apuntas a modificar la estructura del lenguaje, el comentario de Candid Moe, creo que es lo que se acerca a lo que buscas.

Comment: Añadir palabras reservadas implica crear una versión propia de Python, modificando sus fuentes (que están en C) y recompilandolos para crear un nuevo intérprete. Si se hace, no debería llamarse ya Python para no inducir a error. Por otro lado la parte realmente compleja no sería añadir palabras reservadas sino dotarlas de significado. ¿Para qué servirían esas nuevas palabras? Eso exigiría cambios más profundos en el código de Python. Los creadores de python son reacios a añadir nuevas palabras reservadas para mantener compatibilidad hacia atrás. Por eso por ejemplo reusaron las palabras ...

Comment: ... `yield` y `from` (que ya eran reservadas) para crear la funcionalidad `yield from`, en vez de añadir un keyword nuevo para esa funcionalidad. También por lo mismo reusaron la palabra `else` que ya existía para los condicionales, para usarla como parte de un `for` con el significado de "si no se ha abandonado con break", en vez de crear una palabra nueva para eso.